# how to send parameters from js to php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I don't know what i'm doing wrong and im stuck in this part of my project so any help would be appreciated

here is my html:

```
<form id="form_search" method="post" action="/controler/something">
<select id="tip_fam" maxlength="100" >
<option value="1">something 001</option>
<option value="2">something 002</option>
<option value="3">something 003</option>
<ul id="print" class="bot"><li>Print</li></ul>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#print").click(function(){
        url = base_url+"index.php/almacen/product/create_pdf/"+$("#tip_fam").val();
        window.open(url,'',"width=800,height=600,menubars=no,resizable=no;")
    });
```

Php (codeigniter) :

```
public function create_pdf(){       

    $tip_fam = $this->input->post('tip_fam');
```

i thought i could get the value of the select this way but when i print it in a var_dump(), it shows me "boolean false".

Comment: can't make a post with `window.open` ... need to submit form to `_blank` target, or use a `get`

Comment: Like what @charlietfl said, to access the `post` data you have to submit the form. What you're doing is just opening a new window.

Comment: thanks for answering, i'm going to try as @charlietfl says but i'm wondering if there is a way to send parameters to that php function

Comment: sure, as query string `get` params or codeigniter url segments

Comment: i think i didn't explain it properly. i have more than one button and i did a submit already so i thought opening a new window with js would submit the form but i was clearly wrong, do you have an example how i can do that please?

Comment: on click of a button you want to submit a form??

Comment: i want to send some values from my html form to my php function when i click that button. i thought i could send them in the url as i show in the code but it's not working

Comment: if you want to send in url, you shud capture the value as parameter for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to use javascript. I would do it this way.

EDIT: You can have more than one submit button. Just check it in your function.

View:

```
<form id="form_search" method="post" action="/controller/something">

    <select id="tip_fam" maxlength="100">
        <option value="1">something 001</option>
        <option value="2">something 002</option>
        <option value="3">something 003</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="print" id="print" value="Print">
    <input type="submit" name="print" id="print" value="PrintAndSave">

</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function something()
{
    // Check which button was clicked
    $submit_button = $this->input->post('print');

    if( $submit_button == 'print' )
    {
        // Do print
    }
    elseif( $submit_button == 'printAndSave' )
    {
        // Do print and save
    }
}
```

Comment: i was trying to do it that way because i have more than one bottom and one of them is already using that action

Comment: What do you mean by more than one bottom? You meant more than one button? Like you already have  a submit button so this is another button?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i meant i'm sorry my mistake

Comment: thank you, i didnt know this could be done i'm going to try it now

Answer (score 2):

to send value in url and to use in controller, you should capture that vales in parameter of the function. Change your code like this, it will work.

```
public function create_pdf($tip_fam){       

     echo $tip_fam;// will echo the value which you passed from view.
```